# Web API Unit test for exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I wrote a unit test for exception. But looks like it is not working correctly. It is always saying '404 Not Found' Status. that means url request not found. If I paste same url on browser it `HttpResponse.StatusCode` says `BAD REQUEST`.

I don't understand why it is not working for Unit test.

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void GetTechDisciplinesTestException()
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:51546/");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}");
        using (var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:51546/api/techdisciplines/''"))
            using (var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
            {
                //Here Response Status Code says 'Not Found', 
                //Suppose to be 'Bad Request`
                Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response.StatusCode);
            }
            server.CloseAsync().Wait();
        };
    }
```

I tried with `HttpSelfHostServer` which works fine and it uses IISExpress.

```
 [TestMethod()]
    public void GetTechDisciplinesTestException()
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {               
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:51546/api/techdisciplines/''"))
            using (var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response.StatusCode);
            }               
        };
    }
```

So I dont know `HttpSelfHostServer` is not wkring in the code? How to force `HttpSelfHostServer` to use `IISExpress`?  How to deal this?

Comment: I'd use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to see the differences between the two requests.

Comment: I did now. Browser 400-Bad Request, but Unit test request not showing in Fiddler.

Comment: you may need to configure your .NET project to use Fiddler's proxy. This might help: http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp

Comment: you should really be testing your apicontrollers, not making a web request.

Comment: to get fiddler to work, change your request url from 'localhost' to 'localhost.'

Answer (score 9):

Leaving aside why your specific method isn't working, could I suggest that you don't bother testing that particular behaviour via an HTTPRequest - just test directly against the controller class:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(HttpResponseException))]
public void Controller_Throws()
{
  try{
       //setup and inject any dependencies here, using Mocks, etc
       var sut = new TestController();
       //pass any required Action parameters here...
       sut.GetSomething();
     }
    catch(HttpResponseException ex)
    {
       Assert.AreEqual(ex.Response.StatusCode,
           HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
           "Wrong response type");
throw;
     }
}
```

Since this way you are truly "unit testing" that behaviour on the controller, and avoiding any indirect tests

For example if your controller goes off and tries to hit a database before you throw your `HttpResponseException`, then you're not really testing the controller in isolation -- because if you did get an exception back you'd not be 100% certain what threw it.

By testing directly you can inject for e.g. Mock dependencies that will do nothing other than what you tell them to do.

Comment: How would you use this technique if your POSTing a multi-part with files ?

Comment: @guiomie for that type of behaviour I might be inclined to use an HttpRequest during integration testing phase, but for unit-testing, you can do this with Mocks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308899/unit-test-a-file-upload-how

Comment: You never can use Try Catch structure in Test!
you always need to configure your setup!

Comment: @FelipeAugusto - not sure what you mean, in the example test we need to catch the exception that we expect to be thrown in order to inspect and verify it is what was expected. I deliberately did not include code showing setup of the Mock, so as to keep it clear. Feel free to clarify, I'm genuinely confused what you meant!

Comment: @StephenByrne check this part of code, using XUnit

    [Fact]
        public void ThrowExceptionIfShipIsNull()
        {
            //Assert
            Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => 
            Battleship.GameController.GameController.CheckIsHit(null, new Position(Letters.H, 1)));
        }

Comment: @FelipeAugusto - ok I get what you mean now, but the example code is simply illustrative, not meant to be using any specific framework, and not meant to be taken literally...by all means feel free to edit and replace with how you think it should read :)